# I get an error when trying to deploy my app to Vercel. What does it mean by "Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI""?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, vercel

Whenever I try to deploy my app to Vercel it fails with an error
`

```
Error: Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"
    at 7000 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/748.js:136:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at 4186 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:20:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:470:39)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:471:77
    at __webpack_require__.X (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:108:21)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:471:47
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:474:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
```

`and`

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:959:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
```

`I am new at using MongoDB with Next.js and don't understand what I am missing. Here's my env.local minus my username and password`

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.z74c5nt.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

`

I have tried changing the MONGODB_URI but I nothing else works. I've googled and looked for an answer and can't find anything else related to the same issue.

Comment: did that connection string work in dev? you were able to access to mongodb in dev?

Comment: When deploying the project on Vercel you should populate your env variables via the project console. For more see https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables